# Spring Security - externalize value of "requires-channel"

Tags: spring, spring-security

I need to support both HTTP and HTTPS in my Spring Security file and dynamically switch between those at runtime.

So I am trying to create properties file which would contain one of any/http/https, but that won't parse the XML config.

**Spring Security config:**

```
<sec:http entry-point-ref="portalEntryPoint">
    <sec:anonymous />
    <sec:intercept-url pattern = "/portal" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"
            requires-channel="${user-security.login.channel}" />
    <!-- rest omitted -->
</sec:http>
```

**Properties file:**

```
user-security.login.channel=https
```

I am getting following error:

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-enumeration-valid: Value '${user-security.login.channel}' is not facet-valid with respect to enumeration '[http, https, any]'. It must be a value from the enumeration.
```

I am using Spring 3 and Spring Security 2. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you specified [`PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html)?

Comment: Can you print / debug `${user-security.login.channel}` value from that XML config somehow? For example create dummy bean, set some property to the problematic value and see what it really contains.

Comment: @Xaerxess It works without any problems ... it's just Spring Security config must know at XML parsing time that it's one of those three values ...

Comment: So maybe [submit an issue](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC) or ask on Spring Security forums about this.

Comment: By the way, Spring Security 3 doesn't restrict values for that attribute, perhaps it would be able to handle external properties. Can't you move to Spring Security 3?

Comment: Unfortunatelly no, we have legacy services written againts Spring Security 2.0.4 APIs ... well I tried to used SS3, see my previous questions but I am probably stuck with 2.0.x

Comment: 2.0.4 has known vulnerabilities, so you should at least be upgrading to the latest 2.0.x version unless you are certain they don't apply in your case. 2.0.x isn't actively developed so if you want this functionality you'll probably have to patch the bean definition parser code yourself to make this property dynamic. You should definitely be planning an upgrade path to 3.1.x if you think the code will be used in the long-term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you absolutely MUST then use profiles to configure your portal entry point. Obviously this means a lot of copy and paste in your spring config ....

Example from springsource docs :

```
<bean id="transferService" class="com.bank.service.internal.DefaultTransferService">
    <constructor-arg ref="accountRepository"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="feePolicy"/>
</bean>

<bean id="accountRepository" class="com.bank.repository.internal.JdbcAccountRepository">
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>

<bean id="feePolicy" class="com.bank.service.internal.ZeroFeePolicy"/>

<beans profile="dev">
    <jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource">
        <jdbc:script location="classpath:com/bank/config/sql/schema.sql"/>
        <jdbc:script location="classpath:com/bank/config/sql/test-data.sql"/>
    </jdbc:embedded-database>
</beans>

<beans profile="production">
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/datasource"/>
</beans>
```

link http://blog.springsource.com/2011/02/14/spring-3-1-m1-introducing-profile/

Comment: OK thanks for update. So I used profilex for security:http config and it works well for me.

Answer (score 1):

This was not possible in Spring Security 2, you must use Spring Security 3.0+

There was [an issue](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-1201) filed regarding this support that was fixed prior to the release of Spring Security 3.0.